# If a source voltage has a phase equal to 0, can we consider it as a DC voltage?

Tags: power-electronics, electricity

Example:

\$v(t)= 5 cos(0t)\$ and \$s(t)=5 sin(0t)\$

Are \$v(t)\$ or \$s(t)\$ DC or AC as their phases are null?

Comment: You are using "phase" incorrectly.  You mean "frequency"  -- and yes, zero frequency is a DC signal.

Answer (score 6):

Well, if your signal is:

\$ sin( 2 \pi f t + \phi )\$

... with \$\phi\$ being the phase, then your example signal \$ sin (0 t)\$ has both zero frequency and zero phase.

The distinction between AC and DC is based on frequency, not phase. "Alternating Current" means that it changes polarity with time, and this implies a frequency. Thus your signal is DC and not AC.